# Persisting "ONE" part of OneToMany relationship of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities A and B and A is associated to many Bs. If I have a UI where I can updated records of entity A and then in the back end I will get that entity based on the id from the db and set the new values in the object of A that I got from the UI and then I will hibernate save function. Now the question is that as we have a list of Bs for each A and there is no change was there to that list of Bs does hibernate still updates same records of B entities and say if A had 10 rows of B associated with it, will it run 11 queries? 1 for the actual data change in the A and 10 for the associated Bs?

Regards,

Comment: no, as far as I know, it won't. Hibernate will try to calculate how many inserts, how many updates, how many deletes, etc, before executing actual queries. There is also special orders of how those queries get executed one by one. You can actually see them if you turn on the log. In your case, because the B table records does not update, it will not generate update query.

Comment: I am curious through how would Hibernate know which queries to run may be based on when we call setter methods on specific objects of Bs which are associated with A?

Comment: I am not really clear about that. But I think the "equal" method in the entity class can be used to check whether there is update to the object, and the ID fields can be used to determine whether it is a new record or updated existing record.